# How to set no "fast forward" as default when using git merge

Tags: git, git-merge

From the [git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging):

> You’ll notice the phrase "Fast forward" in that merge. Because the commit pointed to by the branch you merged in was directly upstream of the commit you’re on, Git moves the pointer forward. To phrase that another way, when you try to merge one commit with a commit that can be reached by following the first commit’s history, Git simplifies things by moving the pointer forward because there is no divergent work to merge together — this is called a "fast forward".

However, the side effect of this "fast forward" is that if you have a feature branch with multiple commits you will lose the historical context of the feature when you merge back into master. In other words, the commits wont be grouped together as part of this feature.

```
with fast forward:     x---x---x---x---x---x---x

without fast forward:  x---x---x         x---x---x---x
                                \x--x--x/
```

The manual way is to `git merge --no-ff`

Does anyone know how to set this as a default?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Set the config variable `merge.ff` to `false`:

```
git config --global merge.ff false
```

(Without `--global` to limit the effect to the current project)

Comment: but be aware that `git pull` (without --rebase) is doing a merge and hence will create an (usually unwanted) merge commit.

Comment: Oddly enough, when I "git merge mybranch" it does not fast forward, even though one is possible.  When I use the --ff option, it does fast forward.  What's odd is that the merge.ff does not appear to be turned off at any level, so --no-ff seems to be the default behavior for me.  But --ff is supposed to be the default: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---ff  .  Anybody got any clues?

Comment: @michas is there a solution to applying it only for merges but not a git pull?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who wants to keep the fast forward on pull - you can override the merge.ff config for the pulls with the pull.ff config

```
git config --global pull.ff true
```

More info here:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullff

Comment: I think to keep ff option on pull it shuld be TRUE in config file.